deductive reasoning and first principle
In continuation of Are the concepts of reductionism and first principles the same? my next question is what is the relationship between first principle thinking and deductive reasoning ?

See Aristotle. First principles, being the starting points for deduction, cannot be deduced.

+1 Not because of condescension but for originality.

I upvotef this question however you have asked a simalar question and I based my upvote on originality and repetition is not originality. :-(

Reasoning from axioms to conclusions uses deductive reasoning, but that does not mean that all forms of deductive reasoning are from axioms. For instance, we know that all dogs have four legs. If we are now told that Zeno is a dog, we can deduce that Zeno has four legs, but this is not reasoning from first principles.

I would suggest a better example because dogs can have other numbers of legs, but I get your point--that some things just are as they are/that some knowledge is just apparent. And we can use deduction on these.

The logic of syllogisms is deductive logic. The set of mortals contains men, and the set of men contains socrates. Categorical syllogistic logic socrates is a mortal determined by deductive logic or set theory. Else, there is no consistency between the two.

Reductionism is not holism. Holism is not Reductionism. A or Not A . Unless A and Not A have the same conclusion.

How does A and not-A having the same conclusion have to do with anything?

If reductionism is true and holism is true then A and not A are true a necessary condition of a logical And. If reductionism is true and holism is true either the truth of one of those contradicts the other and the conclusion is false. But if both are true each way is a singular determinor of the truth. Simple SQUIRREL.

What? None of that made sense. Why is “A or not A” true unless A and not A both have the same conclusion?

Sorry its a function of rambling.  If Boolean logic requires a truth to both propositions A and not A then the truth of this  logical operator is true if A and Not A are true. If A and not A are false then either A or its antecant are false. Logic is confusing

@PW_246 when A and not A are true ie determinism and holismn are both true. There has to be truth regardless of the method to determine it!!

If you say reductionism is a method of achieving truth then either that method is true and the other method is false. The other method is holism?

Are there any other schools of thought my school was comprehensive and not private and I didn't learn shit from  a comprehensive determination!!

@Community  do you hear public school arguing such a simple statement ?  Do you here a private school pupil making a practical decision and executing the solution to a problem ?

Just to labour the point.  Reductionism and holisimm are two diametrically opposing concepts however both can be true and one not at the expense of the other. Think about this shit!!
